# iOS remove UITableViewCell internal margins in xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` custom. At the top I need to attach a full size view.
But the cell has an internal margin and the constraints came out like this:

[image]

I really need to remove this negative value and set the constraints to 0 - 0 - 0 - 0.

Answer (score 3):

You just unselect **Relative to Margin** option in constraints, If the constraints were already added.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the Edit button and change them there, or when you set up the constraints you can uncheck the margin checkbox and set then to zero by the method shown below.

[image]

Comment: Superb answer. Just what I was thinking.